# primeng - listbox : item not selected

Tags: primeng

I copied the code in:
[primeng-listbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox)

But with my primeng version (8.0.2) when I click on an item, it is not selected.

Can you please help ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" inside the p-listbox tag,
you can see example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xwxi6u?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ylrem3

Comment: Thank you very much ! The difference is "styles" in angular.json.  I found it thanks to your working project. Your help is highly appreciated. Best regards.